# how to get date from august 02 to september 02

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Which prints current date. the below.

is there any method which gives from date's from august 02 to september 02.

```
 NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSLog(@"%@",dateString);
```

Comment: Will you please elaborate you question? What do you exactly want to do?

Answer (score 2):

```
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd"];


int nrOfDays = 30;

for(int i = 0; i<=nrOfDays; i++){
    [comps setDay:i];
    NSDate *date = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comps];

    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"%@",dateString);
}
[dateFormatter release];
[gregorian release];
[comps release];
```

i'm not 100% sure but i think this will work. might be some syntax error because i havn't tried it, no access to xcode currently.

Answer (score 0):

There is a whole section on calendrical calculations in the [Date and Time Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendricalCalculations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007836-SW1).

The important this is to use date components rather than trying to add seconds to a day.

What if the date span was different? What if daylight saving time came in / out of operation? Such things are taken into account when manipulating NSDateComponents that are brittle if you just add seconds.

Answer (score -1):

use `[NSDate dateSinceTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)]`

NSTimeInterval is in `secs` so for 24hrs it will be `86400secs`

jus run a for loop and create a new date by adding timeInterval

`NSDate *newDate =  [NSDate dateSinceTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)]`

Comment: my method works...

i've used it :/

Comment: manipulating dates by adding or subtracting seconds is the wrong way to go about this.

Comment: it works, but it's brittle, and there are better ways of doing it.

Comment: kies..i didn't knew abt dateComponents..i'll keep this in mind..